# Rogue Rate Limiter

Tags: bug, profile-page, rate-limiting

So I was clicking around on the new profile page here on meta and I got presented with this...

[image: Little Too Restrictive]

While I understand the purpose of a rate limiter, seems like its prob. being a little to aggressive..

Comment: Nice job, you broke it!

Comment: @bluefeet I break everything, its a talent really.

Comment: I can only repro this if I run IE11 with the dev-tools open and request every file from the server.

Comment: I'm using firefox, and I just opened the profile page and clicked stuff

Comment: Any browser add-ons/extensions/user scripts that might send requests to the server e.g. review add-on that reloads every second to be the first to review?

Comment: The only browser extension I have is Firebug

Comment: Well, still not a bug and can't see anything different than what has been reported in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why is it being aggressive or unclear.

I believe it can happen if some computers share one IP or your reload button has stuck in pressed condition... you might want to clean your keyboard or buy new then.

...or you are just clicking too fast. I see, you are just wanting to explore the new page as fast as possible, but don't hurry :)

Actually it can happen any time when you are sending too much requests, as it says. That shouldn't relate to the new profile page...

And, btw, seems that your connection is restored now, otherwise you wouldn't have an ability to post?

Comment: Yea, it didnt block me out for to long.  Its not my keyboard or the IP sharing (Unless my ISP is sharing my ip with others which I find unlikely).  Still if the limit is so low it prevents someone from casually clicking around new pages its to low.